# How to maintent main JFrame at the back at all times?

Tags: java, swing

I currently have this command line which is executed at button click from calling form.
new Form().setVisible(true);
What I need is to still be able to access features of the calling form without it coming to the front or sending back the active form.

Comment: If you need to access feature of the original frame, then you need to have a reference to that frame so you can invoke methods defined in the class.

Comment: What I mean is: form1 has a menubar(file, edit, view). Suppose I call form2 then while is running I want to click on 'view' from form1 without form1 coming to the front.

Comment: `new Form().setVisible(true);` Form should be a non modal `JDialog` which uses the calling form as the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Suppose I call form2 then while is running I want to click on 'view' from form1 without form1 coming to the front.

Try using:

```
frame1.setFocusableWindowState​( false );
```

when you create the frame.

The frame may still come to the front, but it won't retain focus.

Comment: That's what I want